# Looking for a way to see if an application is closed

Tags: android

Is there a good way to check if an entire application (not an activity!) is closed by the user? I want to log the time a user spends using the application, so a simple activity `onPause()` ,`onStop()` or `onDestroy()` is not sufficient.

There are several ways an application can be closed, either the user pressing the home button, search button or simply leaving the application. Is there a unified (eg. simple) way to see if any of these things happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are several ways an application can be closed, either the user pressing the home button, search button or simply leaving the application.

Neither of these actually closes the application. The activities will continue to run unless you explicitly call `finish()` or the system kills them when it runs out of resources.

Why is not sufficient to use `onResume()` and `onPause()`?

Comment: Because I wan't to see how much time a user spends in the entire application. Not just the lifecycle of one single activity.

Comment: You can do this in every activity you have and add the timespans together.

Comment: But how would I know when to stop logging? At a certain point I need to know when the user actually stopped using the application.

Comment: Consider the user stopped using your application when none of your activities are on top of the stack (i.e. another apps are in use).

Comment: I was just thinking to difficult I guess. Someone else hinted me on using onUserLeaveHint() and onUserInteraction()

Answer (score 1):

will overriding finalize() to the App class (that extends Application) help for this job ?

if not , maybe a reference inside this class to another class that has this method?